# Sending and receiving an image

Tags: digital-communications, modulation

After studying digital communication courses, I wanted to implement these theories and create an application for sending and receiving a gray image via WiFi between two Raspberry Pi devices. The choice of WiFi modules was arbitrary; my goal is to understand the steps and their implementation.

So, I read an image where each pixel is represented by 8 bits. The first step is to encode the data by assigning them an amplitude and a bit time. I randomly chose NRZ for simplicity (any better suggestions are welcome). For the second step, which is applying a pulse shaping to avoid any Intersymbol Interference (ISI), I am wondering if I should apply it for each pixel sent or for each bit. In the case of a video, which is a succession of images, would it be applied to each pixel as well?

Subsequently, is it necessary to use Amplitude Modulation (AM) to transmit it, or is Baseband Modulation sufficient given that the distance between the two cards is small?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  WiFi (IEEE 802.11) uses a variety of modulation schemes, primarily [direct-sequence spread spectrum (DSSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-sequence_spread_spectrum) and [orthogonal frequency-division multiplexing (OFDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiplexing). For existing WiFi modules like on a Raspberry Pi, there is no need to do any modulation as the hardware will already do it and (mostly) adhere to the appropriate standard.

Comment: @PeterK. I want to apply the theory in digital communication without using existing models

Comment: My recommendation is to start by implementing a BPSK modem using two computers' sound cards and a cable, or a microphone and a speaker. Once you have that working (it will take a while!), start progressing to higher-order modulations and then to RF using an SDR.

Comment: @MouhKramo Then you’re not going to be using WiFi, and I suggest following MBaz’s approach.

Comment: Small distinction to avoid misunderstanding. The sole purpose of pulse shaping is to limit the transmit bandwidth, not avoiding ISI. When we limit bandwidth we can introduce ISI, so proper pulse shaping does this without introducing ISI.  If you don't apply pulse shaping (rectangular pulses) you also will not get ISI.

Comment: @DanBoschen Ah ok I thought that it was a crucial step every time we perform a digital modulation and it's just when we want limit the bandwidth.

Comment: Correct. Although most every time we transmit over the air it is in our best interest to limit bandwidth to efficiently use the spectrum.  (Counter case is GPS since the signal noise density is received below thermal noise.)

Comment: @DanBoschen If you would like to explain for me two other concepts that I didn't understand: coherent and non-coherent demodulation, as well as the error probability calculated from the integral of the tails of the noise spectral density when the noise is higher than (S0-S1)/2

Comment: You could try posting those (separately) as individual questions but as an open-ended question is may be too broad for the Q&A format here (as in requires chapters from a text book). Try detailing what still confuses you from your own research and it may end up being a good question if it can be made more concise. Also see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask